# take username as a parameter to a salt state file (sls)

Tags: salt-stack

I'd like to use saltstack to standardize developers workspaces. As such, I need to take the username as a parameter. This could come from $USER or be typed in. Either would be fine. I see that I could write a grain to expose this, but that seems overly complicated. I'm thinking I'm missing something simpler.

I want to enable something like this

```
https://...../reponame.git:
  git.latest:
    - target: '/home/{{ username }}/src/reponame'
    - user: {{ username }}
```

What is the best/easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not elegant, but effective: use the [`cmd.run` module](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.cmdmod.html#salt.modules.cmdmod.run) to get the user that the Salt minion is currently running as (assuming that the Salt minion is running as user, and not as root):

```
{% set username = salt['cmd.run']('id -u -n') | trim %}

https://...../reponame.git:
  git.latest:
    - target: '/home/{{ username }}/src/reponame'
    - user: {{ username }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily set/overwrite a pillar at state execution.

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/pillar.html#setting-pillar-data-on-the-command-line

So, with a sls (eg. `workstation/gitrepo.sls`) like

```
{% set username = salt['pillar.get']('username') %}

https://...../reponame.git:
  git.latest:
    - target: '/home/{{ username }}/src/reponame'
    - user: {{ username }}
```

You could call

```
salt 'phils-pc' state.sls workstation.gitrepo pillar='{"username": "phil"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% set username = salt['cmd.run']('logname') | trim %}
```

Comment: You should explain your answer a bit.